# DestinationDataProvider error with SAP Configure Connection in Mule 4

Tags: mule, mulesoft, mule4, dataprovider, jco

I have an issue with SAP Configure Connection in SAP Connector in Mule 4.

I'm getting connection error with:

> Connection error. We were unable to reach your service. Check your connection settings and try again. Details: com/sap/conn/jco/ext/DestinationDataProvider
>
> [image: Error Picture from Mulesoft Design Center]

Comment: @ShacharHamuzimRajuan I've approved your edit, but after a few improvements on it, there is nothing left from your changes. So please be sure to remove the fluff from a post in future edits.

Comment: In which product do you see the error from the screenshot? Mule 4 doesn't have an UI.

Comment: This error is from Design Center in Anypoint Platform.